# Android – Am I Doing this Right?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am building an android app that requires a layout to be added programmatically.  This is the line that seems to be giving me a hard time:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rightScreenParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            (int) (screenWidth * 0.25), (int) (screenHeight * 0.94));
```

The variables screenWidth and screenHeight are the width and height of the screen in pixels.  The layout is supposed to be 25% of the width of the parent layout, and 94% of the height.  When I add the parameters to the layout and then add the layout, it takes up the entire screen instead of the dimensions I mentioned.

So am I using this constructor correctly?  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Edit:

I get screenWidth and screenHeight in onCreate():

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels
```

The variable screenHeight is returning as 1184 even though the actual height in pixels is 1280.  The variable screenWidth seems to be fine.  So how can I get an actual screen height in pixels?

Comment: Can you please post the other bits of the code - i.e. creating and adding the layout? Also how you get screenWidth & height?

Comment: `screenWidth/4, screenHeight * 94/100` is probably faster in some cases

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rightScreenParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.Wrap_Parent,samehere);
View.setLayoutParams(rightScreenParams);//your view
//after you add it to the layout then you call
rightScreenParams.width = (int) (screenWidth * 0.25);
rightScreenParams.height = (int) (screenHeight * 0.94);
```

its the same thing but it forces android.

Comment: Presumably you meant to change the values **before** calling `setLayoutParams`, right?

Comment: plausibly **No** i meant every _letter_ to _letter_. if it was for me all i will do is `View.getLayoutParams().width = myWidth;` -(_used plausibly because you used presumably :)_) lol @SanjayManohar